# Can I run a standard OSGI bundle in equinox?

Tags: osgi

I have developed an OSGI bundle with Bndtools, and it can work well in Apache Felix. So can I publish the bundle and run it in Eclipse equinox directly?

Comment: In general, avoid questions like "can I do X" because you can simply answer the question yourself by trying! A better question would be "why can't I do X?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to run your bundle in any OSGi framework that supports all requirements your bundle has. Typically felix and equinox can be swapped quite easily.

Did you get any errors?